# Unable to add specific record type in the criteria while declaring a sharing rule

Tags: record-type, sharing-rule

I have 2 record types: **PSP** and **Closed PSP** of the Case object. While declaring a sharing Rule, I am trying to add **Closed PSP** as a record type in one of the sharing rule. But I am getting the error as

> "Error: Entity: ​Case, Id: U#2e.14ff (RecordType), Name: RecordTypeId,
>   Error: Invalid record type name or ID: Closed PSP"

. While PSP record is getting added successfully.

Comment: Is Closed PSP record type active ?

Comment: Yes it is active

Answer (score 1):

Apart from these 2 record types, I had several other record types. So the character limit allowed only "Closed" instead of "Closed PSP".